# Azure Service Management REST On Android

Tags: android, rest, azure, certificate

Has anyone managed to consume the Azure Service Management REST API from Android ?

What i have done :

- Uploaded my own certificate to azure.
- Followed and implemented tutorials : http://blog.antoine.li/index.php/2010/10/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/ , [Using client/server certificates for two way authentication SSL socket on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064810/using-client-server-certificates-for-two-way-authentication-ssl-socket-on-android)  , [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https) , http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Java/SelfSignedCerts.html (and more...).

Where i am at :

- I am  trying to make a request to get a list of hosted services but i get a 403 Forbidden response.(i believe the server failed to authenticate the request).

What i ask :

- Can anyone please tell me the right steps to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have that cert in the chain on the device. You need to load it and add it to the headers of the request you make.

In C#, I do that by storing the cert as an embedded resource, loading the bytes into a X509Certificate2 class and using that in thevrequest to the API.

Question: why do you need it on the device?

*update*:
Did you add the certificate to the **management** certificates? :o) Just to clarify, there are two ways you can add certificates, one is in the Management certificates under the *Hosted Services, Storage Accounts & CDN*. Make sure you add it under the correct subscription ID, and make sure you call the HTTP with the correct parameters (most commonly the problem in my case).

Comment: I have tried the C# example in .net . It worked (ofc), but i did not manage to find a similar example for Android. 

Response to Question : Because if someone else uses this app, they should be able to upload their own certificate.

Comment: Try running Fiddler if possible and see if there are any differences in endpoint or details of the connections.

Comment: I'm not really able to use fiddler because :

 -When i debug in emulator, the get request gets timed out.(the emulator must be having "trouble"). 

 -When i debug on a device, fidller can't trace the request (ofc).

Comment: Then I suggest you take the code away from the project and get a Java App to work. Figure out if the cause is perhaps somewhere else... Eliminate everything else (emulator, OS)...

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I managed to figure it out. The problem was the client certificate. The problem was the way i exported the .pfk and transforming it into a bks. I recommend using Portecle.

Comment: can anyone tell me how to solve this error (: 403 Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)? This happens when i try to load my image to android device.