# secure socket communication in android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to setup secure socket communication to a server. I have successfully tried the Socket class, but that is not a secure way of communication. From what I gather, SSLSocketFactory and SSLSocket is required for securing communication via sockets. How do i go about implementing these?

I used this code

```
SSLSocketFactory s = new SSLSocketFactory();
socket = s.createSocket(url, port);
```

but eclipse says i cannot instantiate SSLSocketFactory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()` to get an `SSLSocketFactory` instance.

Also, maybe this will be of use to you: [Using client/server certificates for two way authentication SSL socket on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064810/using-client-server-certificates-for-two-way-authentication-ssl-socket-on-androi)