# How to use .key and .pem file to create a socket SSL in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, ssl

My .key file like:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEA1j6eGXbHpqigZ1K//wnuyr5v/L2jFm7dzTtHJx8ZoMQ4CbsG

My .pem file like:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE4zCCA8ugAwIBAgIDBOziMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMDwxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT

I don't know how many steps of authenticate at here. I only want to create a ssl socket to an IP and port, and send/receive data in that socket.
I tried to use keystock, but perhaps I don't understand deep about it, I always get wrong.

Please give me a guide, or sample code.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 9):

I assume that the `.key` and `.pem` file represents your client certificate you have to use for performing an HTTPS client authentication. Unfortunately Java/Android prefers a different format, therefore I recommend you to import both file into a `BKS` file.

Creating a `BKS` file and importing existing `.key`+`.pem` file is very simple using [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/). After starting KeyStore Explorer select *File -> New Keystore -> BKSv1*. Afterwards you can execute *Tools -> Import Key Pair* and select the .pem file. Afterwards KeyStore Explorer will ask you for selecting the .key file.

Finally save the key store protected with a password of your choice.

The created `BKSv1` file can now be used in your Android app. See for example the code posted in this question: [Using client/server certificates for two way authentication SSL socket on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064810/using-client-server-certificates-for-two-way-authentication-ssl-socket-on-androi)

Comment: This is good link. But I create all thing in a thread, and get error: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. Do we need to create thread for it?

Comment: In Portecle 1.9 (not sure about other versions) your `.key` file *must be password protected*, otherwise Portecle will just tell you the key is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a SSL connection, you just need the socket to allow the connection with your server, enabling it as a trusted source. To do so, you need to have your SSL certificate in X509 format and then create your connection as stated in [this article](http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/).

Here's [a guide on generating X.509 certificates](http://www.ipsec-howto.org/x595.html).

Comment: The linked article is about setting an Android trust store, not a key store for HTTPS client auth, therefore it's use is limited. Also the OP does not need to generate (client) certificates as he already have .key and .pem file.