# Client Certificates in android

Tags: java, android, ssl, httpurlconnection, pem

I want a server to validate a client through a certificate. I have the certificate **user_cert.pem** and the key **user_cert.pkey** stored locally.
 How will i do an **httpsURLconnection** authenticating the client to the server?

I have searched, but i am a little bit confused. I found this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) .

The problem is that my certificate is in *.pem format.

Should i  set the KeyStore like this?

```
 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PEM");
```

Sorry, if i give vague information, but i think there is not enough documentation.

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064810/using-client-server-certificates-for-two-way-authentication-ssl-socket-on-androi)  describing
**android supports certificates only in BKS** Format and if we have certificates in **PEM** format, we should change them into BKS format through the **Portecle** GUI software.

I just ask for any source for information about  client certificates in PEM format in android .

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, your private key won't be private anymore if your application is distributed because it can be extracted from an APK easily.

80% of the code needed for using client certificates is in the [official Android documentation (Unknown certificate authority)](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa).
Then, instead of the part with `TrustManagerFactory`, use a `KeyManagerFactory` and call `sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);`.

FYI:

- CRT/PEM is the same certificate format. Only the file extension changes.
- BKS is the Android equivalent of JKS because JKS are not usable in Android.